# Download data from xml using xpath - returns empty list

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath

I am fairly new to using python to collect data from the web.  I am interested in writing a script that collects data from an xml webpage.  Here is the address:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp"
page = requests.get(url)

extractedHtml = html.fromstring(page.content)
guest = extractedHtml.xpath("/guestbook/guest/fname")
print(guest)
```

I am not certain why this is returning an empty list.  I've tried numerous syntax in the `xpath` statement, so I'm losing confidence my overall structure is correct.

For context, I want to write something that will parse the entire xml webpage and return a csv that can be used within other programs.  I'm starting with the basics to make sure I understand how the various packages work.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp"
page = requests.get(url)

extractedHtml = html.fromstring(page.content)
guest = extractedHtml.xpath("//guestbook/guest/fname")

for i in guest:
    print(i.text)
```

In the xpath, you need a double-dash in the beginning. Also, this returns a list with elements. The text of each element can be extracted using .text

Comment: Thank you.  Would you recommend using pandas or beautiful soup for large scale data extraction?  This will work but may be slow as I scale up.  (I also realize this is a different question, so I can 're-post' if needed.)

Comment: I have only used selenium in combination with pandas in the past, so cannot comment on beautiful soup - but selenium is quite easy to learn